# Как обратиться только к одному из элементов класса в css

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Имеется код, который менять нельзя. Как обратиться к конкретному DIV зная его класс и расположение относительно DIV с известным ID. Другими словами нужно обратиться к конкретному элементу без идентификатора.

```
<div id="main_page_right">
   <div class="module">
     <div class="moduletitle">
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Пока писал сам решил вопрос.

```
#main_page_right .moduletitle { /* правая полоса - шапка - главная страница */
    margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;
    text-align: left; z-index: 3;
    border: 2px double #d9dad8; /* Параметры границы */
    border-style: solid;
  }
```

Думаю стоит оставить вопрос, т.к. решения в поисковике не нашёл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно указывать точное наследование селектором parent > child:

```
#main_page_right > .module > .moduletitle
```

но обычно такой метод говорит о плохой верстке (при нормальной используется метод без указания точного наследования, который вы дописали в вопрос)

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто указать порядковый номер элемента:
http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child